# Can Linux detect if a display is currently showing the output from pc?

Tags: display, xrandr

Let's say I have TV connected to both my game console my PC, and TV is currently showing input from game console. Is it possible to tell if TV is currently showing input from my pc? It doesn't have to know the exact device that TV is currently taking input from and displaying, It just needs to know that TV is not showing input from PC.

Comment: In general "NO" , though there are Cases where that is Possible : you have to use HMDI , the Devices & the Ports & the Cables must support CEC / eARC / ARC , the OS & the Device Driver must have that support , Etc. That is not very common yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative answer : The PC only knows that it's transmitting data, it has
no way of knowing what the other end is doing with it.

The PC will generally monitor continuously the status of the connection.
If the connection is cut off, the PC will detect that it's getting
no response from the other side and will act accordingly.
But otherwise it can't know what is appearing (or not) on the monitor,
as long as the monitor is answering status requests.

Comment: Thank you. It was originally come up while I was having discussion with my friend, saying that windows is capable of detecting when monitor goes off or tv has changed input source, treating it as monitor disconnection and reconfiguring its environment from dual monitor setup to single monitor.
But I wasn't having any of that on my KDE Neon and wanted to know that if it is true